# Run nosetest with selenium grid

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid, nose

I'm currently trying to run python UI automations using selenium grid and nosetest. I finished setting up the hub and two nodes. I tried to run the tests by the command below:

```
nosetests-2.7 --tests=ui_tests/sample_tests.py --tc-file=conf/config.ini --nologcapture -v --with-holmium --holmium-browser=chrome --holmium-remote=http://<my_hub_ip>:4444/wd/hub --process-timeout=600 --holmium-browser-per-test --holmium-ignore-ssl-errors --processes=2
```

I get the error message on nodes below after some test cases finished running:

```
INFO:I/O exception (org.apache.http.nohttpresponseexception) caught when processing request to <>->http://<my_hub_ip>:4444: The target server failed to respond
```

I have done searching for this issue, but didn't find anything useful to solve the problem. I'm wondering if it is because the VM that is acting as the hub is not powerful enough.

I'm using `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1` and `nosetests-2.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem. Just download the newest version of selenium-server-standalone, it works perfectly. The version I'm using now is 3.0.1. They had a fix of the I/O exception in this version.